# Update Post Meta is adding a value to my serialize array

Tags: posts

I have the following select values:

```
<select name="vibe_quiz_tags[]" id="vibe_quiz_tags" multiple="" class="chzn-select chosen select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
   <option value="">Select Taxonomy</option>
   <option value="4">Test1</option>
   <option value="5">Test2</option>
</select>
```

I post these variables and serialize them with the following code:

```
$categories = serialize($_POST["vibe_quiz_tags"]);
echo $categories;
```

I then get the following code when it is output:
`a:2:{i:0;s:1:"4";i:1;s:1:"5";}`

I update the post meta with the following:

```
update_post_meta($quiz_id, 'vibe_quiz_tags', $categories);
```

When it gets inserted into the database it adds an `s:30` at the beginning. Here is what is actually stored in the database:
`s:30:"a:2:{i:0;s:1:"4";i:1;s:1:"5";}";`

Why is wordpress adding the `s:30` at the beginning?

Comment: If you look at the Codex, under Parameters, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta#Parameters it says the passed array should be raw. `update_post_meta` is serializing your data again

Answer (score 2):

This happens when an already serialized string get serialize again.

Replace

```
$categories = serialize($_POST["vibe_quiz_tags"]);
```

with

```
$categories = $_POST["vibe_quiz_tags"];
```

EDIT:

As mentioned by [czerspalace](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/47406/czerspalace) in the comments, the [Function Reference for update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta#Parameters) states that "this should be raw as opposed to sanitized for database queries".